# laravel 5 eloquent orm relationships get all records not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

[Tables reletions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OcHU.png)

Category.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

  public function getVideo(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Video','category_id','id')->where('categories.kat_name', '=', 'comedy');


    }

}
```

PagesController.php(Controller)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use App\Category;

use App\Video;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

function getCategory($kategori_ad){

    $myvideo = Category::all()->getVideo();

    }


}
```

I want make this : SELECT * FROM categories join videos ON categories.id=videos.category_id AND categories.kat_name='animals' with orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
class Category extends Model {

  public function getVideo(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Video','category_id','id');

  }
}
```

```html
class PagesController extends Controller {

   function getCategory($kategori_ad){
       $myvideo = Category::where('kat_name', '=', 'comedy')->with('getVideo')->get();
   }
}
```

Comment: I add up reletions image.

I want make this : SELECT * FROM categories join videos ON categories.id=videos.category_id AND categories.kat_name='comedy' with orm 

-------erorr: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.kat_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `videos` where `videos`.`category_id` in (1, 2) and `categories`.`kat_name` = comedy)

Comment: I didn't see. I've edited.The code is working.Thank you very much.

Comment: I struggled for a week.Thank you very much Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myvideo = Category::with('getVideo')->get();
```

Comment: thanks but not working  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.kat_name' in 'where clause' –
return $this->hasMany('App\Video','category_id','id')->where('categories.kat_name', '=', 'comedy');
kat_name's categories table field

Comment: I add  reletions image.

Comment: I want make  this : SELECT * FROM `categories` join videos ON categories.id=videos.category_id AND categories.kat_name='animals'   with orm